# How upload files to current working directory in Google Colab notebook?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I uploaded a Jupyter notebook to Google Colab. The notebook accessed a couple of images from local path `/images/pic1.png` How to upload data to the directory in Colab where the notebook is running? Please note that these are temporary files. So, I don't mind them being deleted on terminating the session.

I used Files upload feature but it doesn't seem to upload to Google Drive. I want to upload the folder with the same hierarchy as in the local environment without needing any change in the paths of the files in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The better way I've found is mounting a folder in your Google Drive. Upload the image folder to your drive. After that, in your notebook you write:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After you allow the authentication, you can work using the path "/content/drive/My Drive" with the path for your image folder. Like that:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image("/content/drive/My Drive/images/pic1.png")
```

See more in the notebook with documentation: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb